# Reporting Scores Using PHP / JavaScript

Tags: google-classroom

I have created activities like these:

https://www.ereadingworksheets.com/text-structure-worksheets/text-structure-practice-01/

https://www.ereadingworksheets.com/reading-comprehension-worksheets/google/

They use the Google Classroom button.

When students are done with the quiz, they can currently print, save, or email PDFs of their scores. They can also share their scores to Facebook.

I want them to be able to submit their scores and essay responses to Google Classroom.

I've looked at the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework

But the examples are only in Python.

Everything I've built for this project is based in PHP.

Can I get some examples using PHP that achieve the following goals?

1. Pass graded scores to your API.
2. Pass ungraded essay responses to your API.

Thank you in advance for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [PHP Quickstart for Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/php) which you can use as a reference to start from. Also, there's a bunch of PHP scripts from Google in their [google-api-php-client-services](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service/Classroom) for Classroom API.